# Подсказки в VScode. Как увеличить из скорость появления в vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Я только что перешел с **webstorm** на **vscode** из-за срока действия лицензии, там я привык к моментальному появлению подсказок. Но в **vscode** есть задержка пол секунды что довольно много. Пробовал и в `jsx` и обычном `HTML` и в `styled-components`. С компом всё нормально.
Как это можно изменить?

Comment: к сожалению, все равно задержка остается. Не сравнить с phpStorm

Answer (score 1):

Заходите в `settings-> sugges-> Editor:Quick Suggestion Delay -> 0`